# unexplainable "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" MySQLierror

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am currently trying to do a deletion of some rows in my MySQL database, using MySQLi prepared statements. For starters, heres my code for deleting the rows:

```
elseif ($this->loggedInAs(NORMAL_USER)) {
        $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT messageID FROM messages WHERE messageID = ? AND (from_user = ? OR to_user = ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $messageID, $userID, $userID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($messageID_result);
        $stmt->fetch();


        if (is_numeric($messageID_result)) {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM messagecomments WHERE messageID = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $messageID);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            if ($result) {
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM messagevotes
                                             WHERE messageID = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $messageID);
                $result = $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                if ($result) {
                    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM messages
                                                 WHERE messageID = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $messageID);
                    $result = $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

                    if($result) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;   
                    }

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The part where it goes wrong is descriped in the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\...\DBClass.php on line 768
```

which is the "$stmt->bind_param("i", $messageID);" in the second SQL statement, where I am attempting to delete rows from messagecomments.

The error message normally occurs when there is an error in the SQL statement, but the statement worked perfectly when I ran it in MySQL workbench.

(It may be important to mention that i have done similar delete statements in the same class)

I really can't see what may be wrong. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, you should close the first statement:

```
$stmt->bind_result($messageID_result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

after closing it, the second statement should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To me the error message says that you do not have a prepared statement. The prepare method returns false if something goes wrong, so you should check that. The manual even gives an example:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
   # ...
}
```

And then check for this (manual):

> mysqli_bind_param This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 
>   and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Update: this is only the function that is deprecated, not the stmt method, sorry.

Comment: @RyanVincent who are you commenting to? Don't address the wrong person.

Comment: @RyanVincent I corrected the mention of mysqli_bind_param. You addressed user68621 while meaning me. And my problem analysis was right, if he does not check return codes he will be asking soon about the next thing that 'does not work'.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I did'nt close the first statement after executing it. I thought that I tried it earlier without any luck. 
Anyways, by adding

```
$stmt->close();
```

to the first statement, it all worked out.

So if anyone else run into the same kind of problem, remember to always close your statements when you're done with them.

Comment: I would rather say check return codes from your functions, and if there are errors let them be reported somehow.